# SQL JOIN vars not working

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I'm trying to select variables from 3 tables using 2 left joins.

```
SELECT a.username, a.id, COUNT(c.featured)
FROM user a
LEFT JOIN board b
ON a.id = b.user_id
LEFT JOIN pins c
ON a.id = c.user_id
WHERE c.featured='yes'
GROUP BY b.board_name
ORDER BY COUNT(c.featured) ASC
LIMIT 3
```

This should get the 3 highest scoring boards from the database and arrange them according to how many times they have been featured in ascending order. I'm using this to echo:

```
".$info['b.board_name']."
```

However nothing is showing

Comment: (1) you don't `SELECT b.boardname`, so it isn't in the returned columns (2) if you do, the fieldname will be `boardname`, not `b.boardname`, as the `b.` prefix will be stripped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want `b.boardname` or `a.username, a.id`  in your `SELECT`, but you have to do the `GROUP BY` accordingly:

Try doing:

```
SELECT a.username, a.id, COUNT(c.featured)
FROM user a
LEFT JOIN board b ON a.id = b.user_id
LEFT JOIN pins c ON a.id = c.user_id
WHERE c.featured = 'yes'
GROUP BY a.username, a.id
ORDER BY COUNT(c.featured) DESC LIMIT 3
```

OR

```
SELECT b.board_name, COUNT(c.featured)
FROM user a
LEFT JOIN board b ON a.id = b.user_id
LEFT JOIN pins c ON a.id = c.user_id
WHERE c.featured = 'yes'
GROUP BY b.board_name
ORDER BY COUNT(c.featured) DESC LIMIT 3
```